# how to insert value into xml?

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I am really new to XML and JDOM so I have a noob question, sorry for that. I have a XML file and I want to insert value into it. My XML file is like that;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message>
    <header>
        <messageType>  </messageType>
        <sendFrom> </sendFrom>
        <HostName> </HostName>
        <sendTo> </sendTo>
        <receiverName> </receiverName>
        <date> </date>
    </header>
    <body>
    </body>
</message>
```

So what I want is for example is to add value between `<sendTo> </sendTo>` and also I want to add `<A>` data `</A>` between `<body> </body>`. Can you please tell me how to do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: here is the example http://www.techbrainwave.com/?p=391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch14s04.html

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/MakeupandwriteanXMLdocumentusingDOM.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you use dom,you can do it as follows;

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(inputFile);

        Node messageType= doc.getElementsByTagName("messageType").item(0);//zero tells the order in the xml
        messageType.setTextContent("SMS");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using XStream for XML handling. 
Here, is the link to a 2 minute tutorial: http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html