# How do I insert value in to xml tag

Tags: java, xml, domparser

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SMS>
    <ALERTS>
        <SNO>1</SNO> 
        <MOBILENUMBER>1234567890</MOBILENUMBER> 
        <TEXT>HI</TEXT> 
        <TIME></TIME> 
        <RESPONSEID></RESPONSEID>
    </ALERTS>       
</SMS>
```

I would like to insert string value into XML Tag(RESPONSEID). I have tried with setTextContent and setNodeValue methods which didn't work for me.

Following is my little program:

```
public void selectRecords() throws SQLException
{
    File file = new File("E:\\Workspace\\netbeans-workspace\\DOM_Parser_Sample\\MyXMLFile1.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ALERTS");
    for (int s = 0; s < nodeList.getLength(); s++) 
    {
    Node firstNode = nodeList.item(s);

        if (firstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
        {
            Element eElement = (Element) firstNode;
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpcon.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                    res = response.append(inputLine).toString();
            }
            in.close();
           NodeList responseList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("RESPONSEID").item(0).getChildNodes();
           responseList.item(0).setTextContent(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610894/how-to-insert-value-into-xml) contain some useful links and responses.

Comment: `DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(inputFile);

        Node messageType= doc.getElementsByTagName("messageType").item(0);//zero tells the order in the xml
        messageType.setTextContent("SMS");` Even this example is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code to check the node name and values: I hope this will help your to resolve your issue.

```
    Node alertNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("ALERTS").item(0);
    NodeList nodeList = alertNode.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        System.out.println("NodeName:" + node.getNodeName() + ":TextContent:" + node.getTextContent());
        if ("RESPONSEID".equalsIgnoreCase(node.getNodeName())) {
            node.setTextContent("RESPONSEID-1");
        }
    }
```

/** Just verify the set value */

```
    Node resNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("RESPONSEID").item(0);
    System.out.println("NodeName:" + resNode.getNodeName() + ":TextContent:" + resNode.getTextContent());
```

/** To save the file as MyXMLFile1-test.xml*/

```
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("MyXMLFile1-test.xml"));
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

**You just need to access "RESPONSEID" node and set Text Content.**

Comment: When I verify the set value: I get the output as RESPONSEID-1 but when I open the actual xml file, its not updated in the file.

Comment: @kittu you have to save that to file. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: I didn't figure out that I have new Transform and add to file. Thanks a lot for helping me out :)

Answer (score 1):

You only had a small oversight. When you do `getElementsByTagName("RESPONSEID").item(0)`, you get back a node. You don't want the child elements of that node (there are no child elements). Instead, you directly want to set the text content of that node.

Change the two lines in your code and it works:

```
Node responseList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("RESPONSEID").item(0);
responseList.setTextContent(res);
```